# shell script using a variable that contain special characters

Tags: shell, redis, special-characters

I am using Redis in shell script and I am triying to set a value of a key

Here is my script that works fine:

```
:/# redis-cli JSON.SET etat . '{"name":"Eric"}'
Ok
```

but when I use a variable that contain my Json I am getting that:

```
:/# json="'{\"name\":\"Erci\"}'"
:/# ehco $json
'{"name":"Eric"}'
:/# redis-cli JSON.SET etat . $json
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'JSON.SET' command
```

I tried :

```
:/# redis-cli JSON.SET etat . ${json}
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'JSON.SET' command
```

and:

```
:/# redis-cli JSON.SET etat . "$json"
(error) ERR JSON lexer error SPECIAL_EXPECTED at position 26
```

Can someone help, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the single ticks inside the variable:

```
$ json="{\"name\":\"Erci\"}"
$ redis-cli JSON.SET etat . "$json"
OK
$ redis-cli JSON.GET etat
"{\"name\":\"Erci\"}"
```

Comment: Bien sur, de rien ;)